# The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#

I have a type of Datetime,in database when i want to save  `DateTime.Now` all thing is ok.but when i want save my value i get error

```
                LogTime = log.AnswerTime ?? DateTime.Now
```

The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

LogTime value is:`4/3/2013 12:05:04 PM`

I think all thing is ok but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET DateTime2 and DateTime both map to System.DateTime so there isn't any conversion.  The problem comes from how your database handles the two data types.  MSSQL, for example, treats both of them differently.  In MSSQL DATETIME supports 1753/1/1 to 9999/12/31, while DATETIME2 support 0001/1/1 through 9999/12/31.

This means if you are reading a value of null out of your database from the DateTime2 column, you will be getting 0001/1/1 which most definitely IS an out of range value.

.NET provides some help on this for you and you can read up on it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx.

Make sure you are using your SqlDb types and, if you are using data grids making sure that your columns properly use typeof e.g.

```
new DataColumn("myDate", typeof(DateTime))
```

Comment: This is not the reason for the error, as a null *log* date would default to using 'DateTime.Now' *in the code supplied above*. `DateTime.Now` should always be a valid value for a SmallDateTime field (unless you set your PC clock back 300 years), however I am currently experiencing exactly the same error while trying to simply save a 'DateTime.Now' value of {04/10/2013 12:49:00} into a SQL SmallDateTime field. It is frustrating that I cannot find a correct answer anywhere on SO.